# Angular checkbox required issue

Tags: angular

I am having an issue with a checkbox in a dynamic form.  The required checkbox never changes to ng-valid.  I am using Validators.requiredTrue.

[STACKBLITZ DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-if2vit-jg2lhx)

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the type of checkbox directly rather than via parameters

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-if2vit-1qksnm?file=src/app/dynamic-form-question.component.html

```
 <!--<input *ngSwitchCase="'checkbox'" ... [type]="question.type"> -->

 <input *ngSwitchCase="'checkbox'" .. type="checkbox">
```

---

*References*

- [Dynamically created "input" with type checkbox does not work with ngMode](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7329)